# what is the solution for this error showing in console(debug) and also in textfield is not displaying data(String) is not working

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to display the data from my server in textfield. I have collected the data from the server using JSON and I converted into the string and integer variable, I'm not able to access this variable from outside of the class, I'm using PHP MySQL server database. The main problem I'm facing:

When I am running that app on my android phone the data from my server need to be displayed in the "text field" and was not displaying, my laptop & mobile is on the same network.

I'm not able display the String i.e read from json to textfield
And anyone knows how to initialize `view` in this code

This is java file

```
     package com.sun.user.demophp;

        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;




   import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
        import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;

        public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements 
        OnMapReadyCallback {

            private GoogleMap mMap;
            TextView textView ;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.merge);
                // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is 
                 ready to be used.
                SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
                 textView = findViewById(R.id.tvdata);


                }


           public void buclick(View view){


              String url;
                url =  "http://192.168.43.58:10080/androidDemo/create.php?
                District=\"Mysore\"";
                new MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(url);
               switch (view.getId()) {
                   case R.id.bu2:
                       district = "Mysore";

                     url="http://192.168.43.58:10080/androidDemo/create.php?
                District=district ";
        //               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), district, 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         //               break;
        //           default:
        //              
        //       }
           }

            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                mMap = googleMap;

                // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in 
                   Sydney"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            }


            // get news from server
            public class MyAsyncTaskgetNews extends AsyncTask<String, String, 
       String> {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    //before works
                }
                @Override
                protected String  doInBackground(String... params) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try {
                        String NewsData;
                        //define the url we have to connect with
                        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                        //make connect with url and send request
                        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        //waiting for 7000ms for response
                        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);//set timeout to 5 seconds

                        try {
                            //getting the response data
                            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                            //convert the stream to string
                            NewsData = ConvertInputToStringNoChange(in);
                            //send to display data
                            publishProgress(NewsData);
                        } finally {
                            //end connection
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        }

                    }catch (Exception ex){}
                    return null;
                }
                protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(progress[0]);
                        String districts;
                        int afected_people ;
                        int total_people ;

                        districts = json.getString("District");
                        afected_people = json.getInt("DA");
                        total_people = json.getInt("people");
                       textView.setText(district);


        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),district,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


     //Toast.makeText(getText(getApplicationContext(),district,Toast.LENGTH_LONG)).show();
                        calculate(districts,afected_people,total_people);


                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }


                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String  result2){


                }




            }

            private void calculate(String dis, int afected_people, int total_people) {
                        textView.setText(dis);
            }

            // this method convert any stream to string
            public static String ConvertInputToStringNoChange(InputStream inputStream) {

                BufferedReader bureader=new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line ;
                String linereultcal="";

                try{
                    while((line=bureader.readLine())!=null) {

                        linereultcal+=line;

                    }
                    inputStream.close();


                }catch (Exception ex){}

                return linereultcal;
            }
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoFC6.png)

Comment: You may also need to use `childFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25749277/469080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a null pointer exception. you are initializing the Editext after calling the Asyntask.
initialize the views before executing Asyntask.
ie:
rearrange the code:

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.merge);

            textView = findViewById(R.id.tvdata);
```

........

```
            new MyAsyncTaskgetNews().execute(url);
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but I'm a beginner(Student) so... I don't know it is  NullPointerException

Comment: @SureshN  NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an object reference that has the null value . In your case you are instantiating the textview AFTER executing asyntask. You have to instantiate  the textview BEFORE executing the asyntask. please refer my answer. that is not a suggestion , this is the answer. read it carefully

Comment: Thank you for your **ANSWER**..... Sorry I will correct my words and `THANKS`

Comment: @SureshN If this answer has helped you, please accept it by clicking the ✔ icon underneath the score.